# Multiple threads can wait on a semaphore at same time

Tags: multithreading, pthreads, semaphore

Can multiple threads wait on a single semaphore ?
If yes, upon semaphore down which one will be resumed ?

Answer (score 2):

As the [document](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sem_post.html) for `sem_post` suggests,

> If the value of the semaphore resulting from this operation is zero, then one of 
>       the threads blocked waiting for the semaphore will be allowed to return 
>       successfully from its call to `sem_wait()`. If the symbol `_POSIX_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING` 
>       is defined, the thread to be unblocked will be chosen in a manner appropriate to 
>       the scheduling policies and parameters in effect for the blocked threads. In the case of 
>       the schedulers `SCHED_FIFO` and `SCHED_RR`, the highest priority waiting thread will be
>       unblocked, and if there is more than one highest priority thread blocked waiting for 
>       the semaphore, then the highest priority thread that has been waiting the longest will
>       be unblocked. If the symbol `_POSIX_PRIORITY_SCHEDULING` is not defined, the choice of a
>       thread to unblock is unspecified.

Also , as [`sem_wait`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/sem_wait.html) defines in *Application Usage* section, There can be cases of priority inversion involving threads with differemt priority levels

Answer (score 2):

```
Can multiple threads wait on a single semaphore ?
```

Yes.

```
If yes, upon semaphore down which one will be resumed ?
```

Exactly one of them.  Which one depends on OS kernel implementation: the container type that is used to hold the waiting threads.  This is quite likely to be a FIFO queue and so the first thread to call semaphore.wait() will be released first, but you should not design your app in any way that relies on this behaviour.

Comment: Actually, it's unlikely to be a simple fifo. How scheduling works in Linux: http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html. This section in particular: http://oreilly.com/catalog/linuxkernel/chapter/ch10.html#20825

Answer (score 0):

That will be the thread scheduled to execute at that particular CPU cycle.