# Producer Consumer synck using only mutexes and semaphores (no pthread_cond)

Tags: c, linux, pthreads

I'm currently learning how to use mutexes and Semaphores for multithreading in linux using pthreads, and I've been working on an Implementation of mutlti-producer/one-Consumer problem using only two binary semaphores and a mutex to synck access to bounded buffer, but the program doesn't work as planned

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define QUEUESIZE 20
#define LOOP 15
#define MAX_THREADS 10

void *producer (void *args);
void *consumer (void *args);

int lambda;
int queuesi;
typedef struct {
        int buf[QUEUESIZE];
        long head, tail;
        int full, empty;
        pthread_mutex_t *mut; 
    sem_t *sem_notFull, *sem_notEmpty;
} queue;

queue *queueInit (void);
void queueDelete (queue *q);
void queueAdd (queue *q, int in);
void queueDel (queue *q, int *out);
int factorial( int i);           
int poissonfunction(int i);
int rando();

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int max_pro,max_con,j,i;
        queue *fifo;
        pthread_t prod[MAX_THREADS],cons[MAX_THREADS];

        max_con=1;
        max_pro=4;
        lambda=6;
        queuesi=4;  

        fifo = queueInit ();

        if (fifo ==  NULL) {
                fprintf (stderr, "main: Queue Init failed.\n");
                exit (1);
        }


        for(i=0; i<max_pro;i++)  
        pthread_create (&prod[i], NULL, producer,fifo);

        for(j=0;j<max_con;j++)
        pthread_create (&cons[j], NULL, consumer, fifo);

        for(i=0; i<max_pro;i++)
        pthread_join (prod[i], NULL);

        for(j=0;j<max_con;j++)
        pthread_join (cons[j], NULL);     

        queueDelete (fifo);

        return 0;
}

 void *producer (void *q)
{
        queue *fifo;
        int i,insert,sleep_time;     
        fifo = (queue *)q;

        for (i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
            //pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut);
            while (fifo->full)
               {
                    printf ("producer: queue FULL.\n");
                    sem_wait (fifo->sem_notFull);
                }

             pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut);
             insert=rando();     
             queueAdd (fifo, insert);  
             printf("producer item  number%d item produced  %d\n",i,insert);
             pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut);

             sem_post (fifo->sem_notEmpty);
             sleep_time=poissonfunction(i);
             usleep (sleep_time);
        }

        return (NULL);
}                           

 void *consumer (void *q)
{
        queue *fifo;
        int i, d;

        fifo = (queue *)q;

        for (i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) 
        {
            //pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut);
            while (fifo->empty) 
            {      
               printf ("consumer: queue empty\n");
               sem_wait (fifo->sem_notEmpty);
            }
            pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut);
            queueDel (fifo, &d);
            pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut);

            sem_post (fifo->sem_notFull);
            printf ("consumer: recieved %d.\n", d);
            usleep(2000);
        }                 

  return (NULL);
}

queue *queueInit (void)
{
        queue *q;

        q = (queue *)malloc (sizeof (queue));
        if (q == NULL) return (NULL);       
        q->empty = 1;
        q->full = 0;
        q->head = 0;
        q->tail = 0;
        q->mut = (pthread_mutex_t *) malloc (sizeof (pthread_mutex_t));
        pthread_mutex_init (q->mut, NULL);
    q->sem_notFull = (sem_t *) malloc (sizeof (sem_t));
        sem_init (q->sem_notFull, 0, 1);
        q->sem_notEmpty = (sem_t *) malloc (sizeof (sem_t));
        sem_init (q->sem_notEmpty,  0, 1); 

        return (q);
}

void queueDelete (queue *q)
{
        pthread_mutex_destroy (q->mut);
        free (q->mut);
        sem_destroy (q->sem_notFull);
        free (q->sem_notFull);   

        sem_destroy (q->sem_notEmpty);
        free (q->sem_notEmpty);

        free (q);
}

void queueAdd (queue *q, int in)
{
        q->buf[q->tail] = in;
        q->tail++;
        if (q->tail == queuesi)                     
        q->tail = 0;

        if (q->tail == q->head)
                q->full = 1;
        q->empty = 0;

        return;
}

void queueDel (queue *q, int *out)
{                                       
*out = q->buf[q->head];

        q->head++;
        if (q->head == queuesi)
                q->head = 0;
        if (q->head == q->tail)
                q->empty = 1;
        q->full = 0;

        return;                    
}

int factorial(int i){
 if(i==0)
  return i=1;
 else
  i=i*factorial(i-1);
return (i);
}               

int poissonfunction (int i){
    int time,c,t;
    double p;
    t = 1000;
    c = lambda*t;
    p = (pow(c,i)*exp(-c))/factorial(i);
    time =(int) p*t;
    return (time);
}

int rando(){
    int value;
    value=(int) random()/1000;
    return (value);
}
```

Comment: Missing `#include <pthread.h>`.

Comment: each time you use the queue, you shoul dhold the lock, this is not the case, thus you have __many__ races

Comment: you should probably use condition_variable

Comment: Dear kiran Biradar, by using a mutex when inserting to the queue, the writer threads are sequenced, hence avoiding to overwrite the same slot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest to modify your functions like:

```
void *producer (void *q)
{   
    queue *fifo;
    int i,insert,sleep_time;
    fifo = (queue *)q;

    for (i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) {
        pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut); /* take lock */
        while (fifo->full) {  /* check for fullness */
            pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut); /* if full wait for things to be removed */
            sem_wait (fifo->sem_notFull); /* never sleep with lock */
            pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut); /* take lock an recheck the condition to handle spurious wakeups */
        }
        /* here lock is held */
        insert = rando(); /* safely manipulate the queue */
        queueAdd (fifo, insert);

        pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut); /* safely release the queue */
        sem_post (fifo->sem_notEmpty);  /* wake up potential waiters */
        sleep_time=poissonfunction(i);
        usleep (sleep_time);
    }

    return (NULL);
}

void *consumer (void *q)
{
    queue *fifo;
    int i, d;

    fifo = (queue *)q;

    for (i = 0; i < LOOP; i++) { /* careful you don't produce 'enough' */
        pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut); /* take lock before using fifo */
        while (fifo->empty) { /* check is something to read */
            pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut); /* release lock before sleep */
            sem_wait (fifo->sem_notEmpty); /* wait a sometihing to be pused in queue */
            pthread_mutex_lock (fifo->mut); /* take back lock before checking for spurious wakeup */
        }
        /* from here lock is held, queue can be safely maniplated */
        queueDel (fifo, &d); 
        pthread_mutex_unlock (fifo->mut); /* finished -> release lock */
        sem_post (fifo->sem_notFull); /* wake up eventual waiters*/

        usleep(2000);
    }

    return (NULL);
}
```

You need to check spurious wake ups as the semaphore is always notified even if the queue is not empty/full, thus being woke up does not mean the queue is in the correct state, thus a test is needed.

You may use conditional_variable to handle the full and empty event, this would remove the semaphores here.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I tried your solution, and still getting the same thing. I don't want to use conditional variable, because they aren t supported in freeRtos 9.1, so it will be difficult when porting the code :(

Comment: maybe the downvoter can explain his position an propose something constructive?

Comment: @ibtissamlatachi can you explain why it does not solve you problem? actually can you spot a test that would make it clear?

Comment: sorry but the question is not that clear to me... "sometimes the consumer skips some of the inserted items" does look like a many wake up problem... but maybe I'm wrong, let's wait for clarifications...

Comment: sorry for the downvoter again, but sem_post() just wakes up __one__ thread, thus there are no limitation here... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163932/multiple-threads-can-wait-on-a-semaphore-at-same-time

Comment: @OznOg sorry for the confusion so far. It's late here in India I will surely check this in the morning.